# threadlocker destroyed laptop screw holes

Tags: laptop, laptop-repair, repair, physical-damage, screws

Not long ago I decided to use some [loctite 222](https://www.henkel-adhesives.com/us/en/product/threadlockers/loctite_222.html) on the bottom screws of my laptop to keep them from falling out. This was supposed to be a low-strength threadlocker, but yesterday when I tried to open it up, the screws were completely unmovable. I thought I was unscrewing them, but realized too late that turning them had shattered the plastic mold of several screw holes. Now I can't screw the bottom back on or properly secure the cdrom drive.

I'm trying to figure out what my options are for repair and would really appreciate any suggestions on that.

Also, any tips on using threadlocker in the future would be helpful because I still don't understand why this went wrong. Was this threadlocker too strong? Did I use too much? Did things get too hot down there?

Comment: It says *suitable for all metal threaded assemblies*, not metal on plastic. I never seen anyone using such product in a computer.

Comment: “…bottom screws of my laptop to keep them from falling out.” Was this really an issue? I mean @ChanganAuto states clearly stuff like Loctite is for metal on metal, and your laptop has plastic threads with metal screws. The best solution for a basic issue here would have been to use something like plain transparent tape — the kind that is used for taping pieces of paper together — and put a small bit on the threads of the screw and then screw it in that way. You basically want to thicken the screw so it stays in tight. What you did with Loctite is effectively glue the screws into the plastic.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 It's a standard issue in Dell laptops. Not very common, but typical.

Comment: @gronostaj Really? To the point that unscrewing the screws damages the case? Maybe they are using some kind of lightweight Loctite equivalent, but I doubt they effectively “glue” the screws in like what happened here.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I mean screws falling out all by themselves. Both inside the laptop and case screws.

Comment: @gronostaj Oh, so Dell is cheap and won’t even the really cheap blue colored Loctite equivalent on them? Fascinating.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 They do, but for some reason it doesn't always work, or maybe they don't use it everywhere? No idea. At least some screws have the blue thing on them.

Comment: Yeah, I've had issues with laptops in the past where screws would vibrate out and then I'd just be missing screws forever. I guess using threadlocker with plastic was the mistake.

Comment: Also, the laptop screws did have blue stuff on the threads out of the box, which I assumed was blue threadlocker. I'm feeling pretty silly about all of this now.

Comment: They may have used a very weak threadlock, but not in the thread, dabbed on top after the screw was tightened. That would require a magnitude less force to loosen.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use threadlock on insert threads, especially plastic; use them only on single substrate threads, or well-engineered metal inserts [this is more into vehicle engine block* territory, not computer components], ie drilled & tapped into a single piece of metal. Thread inserts, as you have discovered, are not very strong, comparitively.

Your best alternative if you want to prevent vibration loosening screws/bolts is a locking washer, available in a myriad designs & sizes.

[image]

Having said that, no computer vibrates enough to really shake screws loose. Best solution is probably to just tighten them & leave them as is. For the minimal vibrational forces on a laptop screw thread, Blu-Tack would probably be more than enough, even if you were paranoid about them working loose.

The trouble with having wrecked a thread insert is you now not only have to get the screw out of it, but you need to figure out a stronger glue to fix the insert back in.
Threadlock might be good for this;)
It's a bit like superglue in this respect; it doesn't really hold well against shearing forces.
Next time, make sure that the shearing force against the thread insert is less than that against the screw.
From your link -

> Threadlocking Adhesive - low strength. Easy disassembly. Suitable for all metal threaded assemblies.
> LOCTITE® 222 is a low-strength threadlocker that allows the adjustment of screws including countersunk head screws and set screws. Good on low-strength metals which could fracture during disassembly, e.g. aluminum or brass.

No mention of plastic there, at all.

*This entire answer is based on fifteen years years as a maintenance engineer, swearing at cheap insert threads, e.g. steel into aluminium, which also will shear away at the slightest provocation. Your only chance of removal is by being able to get a good grip on the broken insert [this requires a) access to the rear & b) seriously good [expensive] grips; sometimes by drilling out the whole screw/insert assembly, or sometimes by just throwing out the whole thing & replacing with a new one.

*Designed so that wrecking one insert does not wreck the entire engine block.

Comment: I've gotten all of the screws out, but the the inserts are completely shattered into dust. Would it be possible to put down some epoxy or something and then drill into it to create a new hole?

Comment: Not a job I've ever tackled on something as small as a computer, but just filling/drilling epoxy won't give you anything for the screw to bite on. You're going to have to fashion your own insert or see if you could fasten a nut behind the plane.